# Why CanActivate does not redirect after one click?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Login component when I log in a user with the username and password, I have to click twice the login button to start the session.

I even check at this question:
[Angular 7 Guard redirection only works on double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627562/angular-7-guard-redirection-only-works-on-double-click)

I think that that is not my issue, because I am not doing a request to the server from the guard.ts I am doing it from the ts file.

Here is the login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { PersonService } from '../_services/person.service';
import { User } from '../_object/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;
  userField = '';
  passwordField = '';

  constructor(
    private ps: PersonService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('User', '');
    sessionStorage.setItem('Log', '');
   }

   async loginUser() {

     await this.ps.getUserEspecific(this.userField).subscribe(async userObteined => {
      this.user = await userObteined;
      console.log(userObteined);
      if (userObteined.user === this.userField && userObteined.password === this.passwordField) {
        this.toastr.success('Success login', 'Success');
        sessionStorage.setItem('User', this.userField);
        sessionStorage.setItem('Log', 'logged');
      } else {
       this.toastr.error('Error Login', 'Error');
      }
     });
  }
}
```

Here is the guard.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    logger = sessionStorage.getItem('Log');

    canActivate() {
        let logger = sessionStorage.getItem('Log');
        if (logger === 'logged') {
            logger = '';
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using Agular 8

Comment: I am having same issue. Did you found the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the issue correctly, but I have some comments about your flow that maybe can solve this issue.

I'm not sure why you are handling the authentication of the user in the Frontend side. This is really a bad practice and will cause critical security issues.
You will need to send the username and the password instead to the Backend (Which is NodeJs in your case) and let the Backend handle the authentication of your user.

Second thing, there is no need for the `async/await` of the request. You will need to subscribe to the request and wait for the response so it will get executed once the response come.

For the Guard, it should check if the user authenticated/authorized to view the page, if not, then it will redirect him to other page like the login or other error page.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;
  userField = '';
  passwordField = '';

  constructor(
    private ps: PersonService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('User', '');
    sessionStorage.setItem('Log', '');
   }

   loginUser() {

    this.httpClient.post(this.userField, this.passwordField).subscribe(respoonse => {
        this.toastr.success('Success login', 'Success');
        sessionStorage.setItem('User', this.userField);
        sessionStorage.setItem('Log', 'logged');
        this.router.navigate(['/NAVIGATE_TO_THE_DASHBOARD']);
      }, (error) {
       this.toastr.error('Error Login', error);
      }
     });
  }
}
```